# VS Code jupyter notebook root file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm currently facing the problem of not being able to change the notebook file root.  My setup: I cloned a repo via ssh and run the notebooks on a remote jupyter server with VS Code.
My directory structure is something like:

```
workingDir/notebook_1.ipynb
workingDir/subDir
workingDir/subDir/notebook_2.ipynb
```

According to my google searches it should be possible to set the notebook file root in the settings with

```
"jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "${fileDirName}"
```

But unfortunately this does not help and the notebook still run on the default working directory of the repo.

when I run os.getcwd() in notebook_1.ipynb I expect the output
`'workingDir'`

and when I run it on notebook_2.ipynb I expect the output
`'workingDir/subDir'`

However, I get the output `'workingDir'` in both notebooks. This is pretty annoying as in jupyter-lab in the browser I'm able to reproduce the expected behaviour, but not in VS Code.
Note: I can also reproduce the expected behaviour when I run the notebooks on my local jupyter server. So the problem seems to be connected with the remote jupyter server.

Comment: When I use the local jupyter, I can get the cwd correctly. Can you tell me in detail what the result is when using remote? Is it the same directory

Comment: is it possible you just need to lowercase the "N" in "fileDirName"? I have your same config except "${fileDirname}" and that works.